# Is it normal practice to use short CSS classes like .ml10,

Tags: css

I have found several CSS classes which wide used in one webstudio:

```
.m20 {margin: 20px !important;}
.mh7 { margin: 0 7px !important;}
.mh10 { margin: 0 10px !important;}
.mb0 { margin-bottom: 0 !important}
.mb5 { margin-bottom: 5px !important}
.mt0 { margin-top: 0 !important}
.mt5 { margin-top: 5px !important}
etc.
```

There is about 40 same classes in main css file.
They are used as quick modificator.

Is it normal? And why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's perfectly common. It depends what your priorities are.

Do you care about your code readability and maintainability? If you do, then perhaps you shouldn't be using cryptic classes like this.

On the other hand, for a site like Facebook or other high-traffic sites who care about every byte of bandwidth, they may be more interested in keeping their code as short as possible, so they will have the shortest possible class names.

In the case of the specific code you've quoted, I would say that it's not good code, for at least three reasons:

1. It makes heavy use of the `!important` modifier.
   This is almost always a sign of bad code -- if you have to use `!important` a lot, then it is fairly clear that you're not really making good use of CSS. It can also cause problems for other code that needs to adjust the styles for the same elements.
2. The class names are based on the layout design. So `m20` is for `margin:20px`.
   This is bad practice because it ties your HTML (via the class name) to the layout. The whole point of CSS is to separate the HTML from the layout, so using class names like this somewhat breaks that. It also makes a bit of a mess of things if you want the site to work differently on mobile devices compared with desktop browsers; a class name that is tied to a fixed layout style like this makes this much more difficult.
   The preferred way of doing this is to use class names that describe what the element is for. For example, `menuItem` or `infoPanel`, etc.
3. It's bad for your SEO. Search engines use everything in a page to work out what it's about and how to categorise it. That includes things like the names of the classes and IDs. True, these are less important than the actual content, but why have `m20` that does nothing for your SEO, when you could have something that Google will see as relevant.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't call it normal or abnormal, but if you want a human to be able to read and understand it, I wouldn't advise it.

I suppose a smart CSS compressor could rename CSS classes and update the HTML and Javascript to shorten them up, but the output of those compressors wouldn't be intended for a human to read. You'd work with source files and then run the compressor on the source file to generate the gibberish version.

It seems like the classes are abbreviated descriptors of what the selectors actually do, e.g. `.m20` gives everything a 20px margin. My rule of thumb is to use the class to describe what the function is rather than the appearance. So, I might use a `.bright` class. In one design iteration, this could be a bright red color. In a subsequent iteration, it could be changed to a purple color or anything else. Calling it `.bright` instead of `.red` makes the name of the class independent of the "work" it performs.

Comment: Yes, it's abbreviated description. And this make me confused. I think that classes must be more readable. And think that there are not difference between using this and inline styles.. :)

Comment: Technically, there's no difference unless you're using the same style in multiple places. That's what classes are for, to DRY up your style. If you write style="margin:20px" everywhere you need that, you bloat your markup, blur the lines between your structure and presentation, and set yourself back to doing web development like it's 1999. If instead you have a class `.callout` or something, that could mean 20px margin now to set it apart, but it could mean a `float` in the future or even a `position:absolute`. If your class is still `.m20` it will make even less sense than it does now.

Answer (score 2):

They're a bit cryptic, and personally I would use somewhat longer class names, but as long as they're named consistently, they're not a huge problem. The biggest drawback that I would see would be that if you wanted to change the .mh7 from 7 pixels to 8, the name no longer reflects what it is. You'd either have to set up a new .mh8, or remember that .mh7 is really 8. See complaints against *Hungarian Notation*.

Answer (score 1):

### It is common yet questionable practise.

### No need for it

It comes from the false beliefe that short names spare bandwidth and therefore make the page load faster. While this was true once, browsers (all but iE 4 and below, virtually pre-css-area) and well configured web servers use deflate or gzip compression to transmit css files. 
That means that f1 .. f100 takes up no more banwidth that foobar_damn_long_classname_1 .. foobar_damn_long_classname_100. (Left alone some bytes for the first usage)

### Advise against

So my best advise is to use qualified, reasonable long css class names.

- You save time while editing
- You don have to build a compressor
- Google will also favour ".shoppingcart" above ".sc".
- You can ask stackoverflow for help without people thinking "wtf"?

Answer (score 0):

Though there really is no 'normal' on the Wild Wild Web ;) I would note that:

- It is common to the point of existing in millions of pages
- It would be preferable to spell out real names that describe meaning, separated by dashes, e.g.

  - content-header, content-footer, emphasize, main-highlight, margin-small, top-margin-medium ,etc.